# Determine row from grid search style matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing some work with optimal design of experiments, related to the Federov Coordinate Exchange algorithm. This considers a candidate set of points and chooses from them to identify the best combination of points. The problem is, there are scenarios where there are 5^18 (nearly 4 trillion) candidates - there's no way I can pre-compute the whole grid and iterate over it. My thinking was to create a 'virtual' grid and pass in what row I'm on to obtain the correct combination of values. In a simple 2^3 example (3 features, 2 levels each) the grid would look like `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]`

The pattern is pretty easy, for the first column you figure out which half of the data you're in, get the index, subset the matrix, move onto the next column, etc. So I wrote a recursive function that does this for any number of features `k` and any number of levels `d`. Unsurprisingly, it's very slow compared to pre-computing the grid (when possible). Are there are opportunities to improve the algorithm as I have it here, or, are there other approaches I should consider which are superior to recursion?

```py
def virtual_grid(i, k, d, current_k=1, min_val=0, max_val=None, result=None):
    """
    Pull points from a virtual grid
    :param i: which row of the virtual grid
    :param k: how many features (columns) in the grid
    :param d: how many equally spaced values for feature (density)
    :param current_k: which column is currently being iterated over?
    :param min_val: initially 1, used to modify the search space
    :param max_val: initially d**k, used internally to modify the search space
    :param result: placeholder for final results
    :return: list of values for this particular point in the grid
    """
    if max_val is None:
        max_val = d**k-1
    space = np.linspace(min_val, max_val, d+1)
    position = [ind for ind, val in enumerate(space[1:]) if i <= val][0]
    if result is None:
        result = [position]
    else:
        result.append(position)
    if current_k == k:
        return result
    else:
        return virtual_grid(i=i, current_k=current_k+1, k=k, d=d,
                            min_val=np.ceil(space[position]), 
                            max_val=np.floor(space[position+1]),
                            result=result)
```